# byte array to string and inverse : recoverded byte array is NOT match to original byte array in Java

Tags: java, string, arrays

I converted a byte array to string as follow, in Java:

```
String str_bytearray = new String(bytearray_original);
```

and then, I recovered original byte array using string, as follow:

```
byte[] bytearray_recovered = str_bytearray.getBytes();
```

but I wondered when I compared bytearray_original and bytearray_recovered. the result is as follow:

```
[48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 100, -27, 48, -31, 13, -33, 107, -90, 91, -9, 119, 121, -73, 83, -105, 51, -87, -109, -84, 99, 115, -123, 119, -117, -1, -62, 71, -32, 99, 4, -103, -115, -47, 113, -83, 8, -91, 14, -74, 113, -40, -26, 50, 111, 95, 71, -9, 112, 120, 16, 0, 113, -80, 124, -71, 53, -97, 69, -85, 38, -112, -30, -110, 115]

[48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 100, -27, 48, -31, 13, -33, 107, -90, 91, -9, 119, 121, -73, 83, -105, 51, -87, -109, -84, 99, 115, -123, 119, -117, -1, -62, 71, -32, 99, 4, -103, 63, -47, 113, -83, 8, -91, 14, -74, 113, -40, -26, 50, 111, 95, 71, -9, 112, 120, 16, 0, 113, -80, 124, -71, 53, -97, 69, -85, 38, 63, -30, -110, 115]
```

as you can see, two bytes are different from original byte array, that is `-115 to 63` and `-112 to 63`.
Is it possible to solve this problem?

Note: In fact both original and recovered byte array are a public key. First public key is converted to string to store in a file, and then after reading string value of the public key, it should be recovered to verify the signature.

The bytearray_original is generated as follow:

```
PublicKey signPublicKey = keypair.getPublic(); 
byte [] bytearray_original = signPublicKey.getEncoded();
```

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: What is the purpose of this conversion? Do you want to store your byte array as a String somewhere or it's just curiosity?

Comment: @ sainaen, In fact both original and recovered byte array are a public key. First public key is converted to string to store in a file, and then after reading string value of the public key, it should be recovered to verify the signature.

Comment: oh, okay, so probably you're using something like bouncycastle to do your crypto stuff. you may want to try something like `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString()` and `Hex.decode()` — they work for arbitrary binary data.

Comment: @ sainaen, Yes, exactly. But I don't know how can I use your code in myself. I appreciate if you could use it in my code. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, this isn't going to be encoded to a UTF-8 String well because it's kind of a bunch of random data. Instead, you should encode your data using Base64 like in Louis Wasserman's answer or hex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot convert an arbitrary sequence of bytes to `String` and expect the reverse conversion to work.  You will need to use an encoding like `Base64` to preserve an arbitrary sequence of bytes.  (This is available from several places -- built into Java 8, and also available from Guava and Apache Commons.)

For example, with Java 8,

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(myByteArray);
```

is reversible with

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

Comment: Would you please give me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the Louis Wasserman's answer and as long as you have [BouncyCastle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncy_Castle_(cryptography)) in your project, you may use the `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex` utility class:

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
import java.util.Arrays;

class EncodingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytearray_original = new byte[]{48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 100, -27, 48, -31, 13, -33, 107, -90, 91, -9, 119, 121, -73, 83, -105, 51, -87, -109, -84, 99, 115, -123, 119, -117, -1, -62, 71, -32, 99, 4, -103, -115, -47, 113, -83, 8, -91, 14, -74, 113, -40, -26, 50, 111, 95, 71, -9, 112, 120, 16, 0, 113, -80, 124, -71, 53, -97, 69, -85, 38, -112, -30, -110, 115};
        String str_bytearray = Hex.toHexString(bytearray_original);
        byte[] bytearray_recovered = Hex.decode(str_bytearray);
        System.out.println("Results are equal: " + Arrays.equals(bytearray_original, bytearray_recovered));
    }
}
```

This option requires an external library, but it doesn't require Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to specify an encoding, such as UTF-8.

Both the String constructor and getBytes will let you do this, for example:

```
String str_bytearray = new String(bytearray_original, "UTF-8");
byte[] bytearray_recovered = str_bytearray.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

This should result in the same byte arrays.

EDIT: As RealSkeptic points out, you need to figure out which encoding your original byte array is and use that in place of "UTF-8" in the above code.

Comment: Only if the original bytes are actually in UTF-8.

Comment: It should work either way, but the String may not reflect the byte information correctly if the bytes aren't UTF-8. If you want that to happen, just change "UTF-8" to the encoding of the bytes in your array.

Comment: @Trent Small, The situation was worse, even the length is not the same. the result is as follow:

original:
[48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 107, 38, -108, 75, 125, 75, -103, -70, 68, 103, -120, 78, 113, -98, -111, 106, 38, -125, -93, -102, -22, -37, 30, 25, 61, -15, -90, -47, 76, -25, 16, -9, 14, 3, 19, -115, 27, 39, -77, -55, -12, -54, 85, 69, -76, 53, -3, 94, -107, 124, 61, 100, 49, -21, -61, -21, -54, 112, -47, -16, -50, -47, -106, -13].

Comment: recovered:
[48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -17, -65, -67, 72, -17, -65, -67, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -17, -65, -67, 72, -17, -65, -67, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4, 107, 38, -17, -65, -67, 75, 125, 75, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 68, 103, -17, -65, -67, 78, 113, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 106, 38, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 30, 25, 61, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 76, -17, -65, -67, 16, -17, -65, -67, 14, 3, 19, -17, -65, -67, 27, 39, -17, -65, -67,

Comment: continue:
-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 85, 69, -17, -65, -67, 53, -17, -65, -67, 94, -17, -65, -67, 124, 61, 100, 49, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 112, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -47, -106, -17, -65, -67].

Comment: What encoding are your bytes in to begin with? You should figure that out, then replace the instances of "UTF-8" with that encoding.

Comment: @TrentSmall try it with [-40,-46]. If it's not in the charset, it's not going to be converted properly. And if it's not converted properly, replacement characters will be inserted instead, which will yield different byte values in `getBytes`.

Comment: @sas Please do not abuse the comment section like that. If you have long information to add, add it as an edit to your question: "I did so and so and the results I got were such and such", and then you can comment on the answer and say "see the edit to my question".

Comment: @, In fact, the bytearray_original is generated as follow:
PublicKey signPublicKey = keypair.getPublic();
byte [] bytearray_original  = signPublicKey.getEncoded();

Comment: @TrentSmall, I edited my question and added some additional information about how to generate original byte array.